# TextBox in Model Popup is not getting a value of Country triggered by an update-click?

Tags: php, mysql, popup, crud

When I click on an update button, the model-pop-up appears with the same value for all countries. It's always showing India.

I want the country name here:

```
<input type="text" value='. $row['country_name'] .'>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are printing out a modal for each row you have in the database and they all have the same id "myModal", that's the last thing you want to do.

Instead what you need is to have the modal html printed out once and pass the name of the country to it when the user presses the update button using a javascript function.

Comment: how to pass country name to model  using java script ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a class to td

example

```
<td class='country'>
```

you need to give class to the button

```
<button class="update">Update</button>
```

remove the modal popup code on each echo place it in the footer

give a common id to textbox in the popup

```
$(".update").change(function(){
  $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
  var value= $(this).closest("tr").find(".country").text();
  $("countryUpdate").val(value);
});
```